# Pattern for commonly used Underscore.js iteratees

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, callback, underscore.js, code-reuse

I'm working on a financial analysis tool using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and [Underscore-contrib](https://documentcloud.github.io/underscore-contrib/).

I'm often repeating low-level arithmetical primitives. For example, simple summation of an Array:

*code-a.js:*

```
arr_a = [20, 15, 7];
arr_b = [19, 19, 19];

_.reduce(arr_a, function(memo, x) { return memo + x; }, 0);
# => 42
_.reduce(arr_b, function(memo, x) { return memo + x; }, 0);
# => 57
```

I thought about creating a named function to eliminate duplication of the iteratee definition:

*code-b.js:*

```
function sum(memo, x) {
  return memo + x;
}

arr_a = [20, 15, 7];
arr_b = [19, 19, 19];

_.reduce(arr_a, sum, 0);
# => 42
_.reduce(arr_b, sum, 0);
# => 57
```

Then moved on to wrap the `reduce` call to DRY this out even further:

*code-c.js:*

```
function sum(memo, x) {
  return memo + x;
}
function accumulate(vector) {
  _.reduce(vector, sum, 0);
}

arr_a = [20, 15, 7];
arr_b = [19, 19, 19];

accumulate(arr_a);
# => 42
accumulate(arr_b);
# => 57
```

To me, this smells like it's headed for a [mixin](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin):

*lib-a.js:*

```
_.mixin({
  accumulate: function (vector) {
    _.reduce(vector, function(memo, x) {
      return memo + x;
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

*code-d.js:*

```
arr_a = [20, 15, 7];
arr_b = [19, 19, 19];

_.accumulate(arr_a);
# => 42
_.accumulate(arr_b);
# => 57
```

---

Using a mixin gets the job done well. My question is: **Are there any *other* patterns (specific to Underscore.js) for reusing iteratees without using mixins?** I don't have an issue using mixins if that's "the" [only] pattern, I'm just asking if there are any other tactics to solve the problem of callback reuse.

For example, *code-b.js* demonstrates one possible alternative — simply create the iteratee as a named function (perhaps exported from a module to avoid the need for Hungarian-esque naming conventions).

Comment: You should call that `sum` function "`add`", and that `accumulate` function "`sum`".

Comment: I don't think there are any other patterns.

Comment: you might also explore Lodash (which has a [_.sum function](https://lodash.com/docs#sum) built-in)

Comment: @sfletche this is just a trivialized example (besides, in the grand scheme, addition isn't too hard a wheel to reinvent ;-))

Comment: @Bergi maybe not, but you never know until you ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching around, and reading the above comments, *and* lack of responses, it's pretty clear to me the answer is "no."